# How to redirect to another page after ajax call is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am invoking a void method by using JQuery ajax call as below:

```
var options = {

    url: "/Account/Login",
    data: formvalues,
    type: "post"
};

$.ajax(options).done(function () {

// how to redirect the user to home page?

});
```

I want to redirect the user to the home page after he is logged in. Is there a way to accomplish this in jQuery? I tried `window.location.replace`, but it simply displays the page without maintaining any history as such. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be a able to set `window.location`

```
window.location = '/Home/Index';
```

To clarify:

> Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with location as if it were a string in most cases: location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of location.href = 'http://www.example.com'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Answer (score 0):

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript).

Answer (score -1):

use windows.location.href instead